# Error installing VS2010 SDK (setup can't find VS2010)

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to install the Visual Studio 2010 SDK, but the setup fails with the message below.

[image]

My setup is 64-bit Windows 7 with VS2010 Professional. Any hints on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you installed SP1 on Visual Studios 2010?

I'm guessing you're trying to install [this one](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=47305cf4-2bea-43c0-91cd-1b853602dcc5&displaylang=en). However, you need to install the [Visual Studios 2010 SP1 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21307C23-F0FF-4EF2-A0A4-DCA54DDB1E21&displaylang=en).